# Fast Deployment is off and I still receive error message for Android Project on VS 2019 for Mac - Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

My Fast Deployment is uncheck and when I want to build I still receive the message:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(590,5): error XA0130: Sorry. Fast deployment is only supported on devices running Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher.
```

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(590,5): error XA0130: Please disable fast deployment in the Visual Studio project property pages or edit the project file in a text editor and set the 'EmbedAssembliesIntoApk' MSBuild property to 'true'.
0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:24.64

[image: Fast Deployment]

I try to put `Marctron AdMob` but when I install the library I receive this message ?

Is there a way to fix this error message ?

Comment: What is the version of your Visual studio? There is a known issue at Github, you can check it: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/5794

Comment: I try with this command: msbuild YourAndroidApp.csproj -t:Install -p:_FastDeploymentDiagnosticLogging=true -bl but I see the same error. My version is: 8.9.9 (build 3)

Comment: Do you know how to disable or how to skip this error ?

Comment: What is the visual studio version? try to update the latest version.